# I'm following google instructions, but keep getting " Plugin [id: 'com.google.gms.google-services', version: '4.3.15', apply: false]

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, gradle, build.gradle

Firebase website is telling me to change my build files as:

(/build.gradle):

```
plugins {

  // ...


  // Add the dependency for the Google services Gradle plugin

  id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.15' apply false

}
```

and

(//build.gradle):

```
plugins {

  id 'com.android.application'

  // Add the Google services Gradle plugin

  id 'com.google.gms.google-services'

  ...

}


dependencies {

  // Import the Firebase BoM

  implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.2.0')


  // TODO: Add the dependencies for Firebase products you want to use

  // When using the BoM, don't specify versions in Firebase dependencies

  // https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available-libraries

}
```

This is what they look like right now:
(/build.gradle):

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.15' apply false
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

(//build.gradle):

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    namespace "com.example.chat"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.chat"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

plugins {

    id 'com.android.application'

    // Add the Google services Gradle plugin

    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'



}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.2.0')
}
```

My google-services.json file in inside the android/level/app directory and looks like:

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "90796036267",
    "project_id": "chatflutter-92032",
    "storage_bucket": "chatflutter-92032.appspot.com"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:90796036267:android:54ef4c10ee30c08c5527ee",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.example.chat"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "90796036267-7lrefr1ltb27cehouki0p77qdlu4q3ei.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 1,
          "android_info": {
            "package_name": "com.example.chat",
            "certificate_hash": "a84f187140210a747f937ed89ceef6213d9cc676"
          }
        },
        {
          "client_id": "90796036267-lh6arnnstp7sumrft3jfnp8ln19bl08f.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "AIzaSyB4AkDYnF-F14Jisg2gn3JrBkjH4LL0sIQ"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "appinvite_service": {
          "other_platform_oauth_client": [
            {
              "client_id": "90796036267-lh6arnnstp7sumrft3jfnp8ln19bl08f.apps.googleusercontent.com",
              "client_type": 3
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

And yet I keep getting the same error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\cursoFlutter\chat\android\build.gradle' line: 15

* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'com.google.gms.google-services', version: '4.3.15', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.google.gms.google-services:com.google.gms.google-services.gradle.plugin:4.3.15')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Sorry, I've been trying to solve this on my own for a while now but I still don't know what I'm doing wrong. Other people that similar issues had different issues in their files which I don't think apply in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following from your project level build.gradle:

```
plugins { id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.15' apply false}
```

and add the following in the dependency:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
```

Now my project level build.gradle looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    }
}
...
```

This worked for me. But it took about 3 minutes (very long) to build for the first time.